# Почему после сборки в Visual Studio 2017, VB.Net подключенный dll жестко привязан к тому месту где лежал изначально?

Tags: vb.net, dllimport

Ситуация глупая, первый раз работаю на Visual Studio, и все ответы неверны для меня, хотя что уже проще, просто подключить dll!

1. Беру стандартный проект на Visual Studio 2017, .Net, VB.
2. Подключаю через "Добавить ссылку" библиотеку capicom.dll https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=25281
3. Отлаживаю запускаю все нормально.
4. Когда копирую capicom.dll в папку к exe файлу, библиотека не видится, проверяю это так, переименовываю файл capicom.dll в том месте где он лежал изначально.
5. Попытка менять параметры подключения библиотеки не помогает, "копировать локально" в параметрах не помогает. 
   В путях 
   c:\users\alex1\source\repos\WindowsApp1\WindowsApp1\obj\x86\Release\Interop.CAPICOM.dll
   все верно, но Interop.CAPICOM.dll который создается студией, и гораздо меньше по размеру, бесполезен без оригинального файла capicom.dll который жестко привязан к определенному пути, что не дает возможности запустить программу на другом компьютере.

Вот код класса

```
Public Class CSP

Public Const CAPICOM_LOCAL_MACHINE_STORE = 1
Public Const CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE = 2
Public Const CAPICOM_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_USER_STORE = 3
Public Const CAPICOM_SMART_CARD_USER_STORE = 4

Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_SHA1_HASH = 0
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_SUBJECT_NAME = 1
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_ISSUER_NAME = 2
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_ROOT_NAME = 3
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_TEMPLATE_NAME = 4
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_EXTENSION = 5
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_EXTENDED_PROPERTY = 6
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_APPLICATION_POLICY = 7
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_CERTIFICATE_POLICY = 8
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_TIME_VALID = 9
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_TIME_NOT_YET_VALID = 10
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_TIME_EXPIRED = 11

Public Const CAPICOM_VERIFY_SIGNATURE_ONLY = 0
Public Const CAPICOM_VERIFY_SIGNATURE_AND_CERTIFICATE = 1
Public Const CAPICOM_AUTHENTICATED_ATTRIBUTE_SIGNING_TIME = 0
Public Const CAPICOM_AUTHENTICATED_ATTRIBUTE_DOCUMENT_NAME = 1
Public Const CAPICOM_AUTHENTICATED_ATTRIBUTE_DOCUMENT_DESCRIPTION = 2

Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_INCLUDE_CHAIN_EXCEPT_ROOT = 0
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_INCLUDE_WHOLE_CHAIN = 1
Public Const CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_INCLUDE_END_ENTITY_ONLY = 2
Public Const CAPICOM_PROPID_KEY_PROV_INFO = 2

Public Const CAPICOM_INFO_SUBJECT_SIMPLE_NAME = 0  
Public Const CAPICOM_INFO_ISSUER_SIMPLE_NAME = 1   
Public Const CAPICOM_INFO_SUBJECT_EMAIL_NAME = 2   
Public Const CAPICOM_INFO_ISSUER_EMAIL_NAME = 3    

Public Const CAPICOM_ENCODE_ANY = -1
Public Const CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64 = 0 
Public Const CAPICOM_ENCODE_BINARY = 1 
Private Store As CAPICOM.Store
Dim Certs As CAPICOM.Certificates
Dim xcert As CAPICOM.Certificate
Private SignedData As CAPICOM.SignedData
Dim SignedByte As Byte
Dim SignedBase64 As String
Private Signer As CAPICOM.Signer
Dim cn As String
Dim test_msg As String
Dim StoreName As String
Dim mOutType As Long
Dim buffer As Byte
Dim certName As String

Public Sub New(Optional ByVal StoreName As String = "MY", Optional ByVal StoreLocation As Integer = CAPICOM_CURRENT_USER_STORE)
    Store = New CAPICOM.Store
    Store.Open(StoreLocation, StoreName)
End Sub

Public Function findCertByName(ByVal name As String) As CAPICOM.Certificates
    Dim Certs = Store.Certificates
    If Certs.Count > 0 Then Certs = Certs.Find(CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_TIME_VALID, Now)
    If Certs.Count > 0 Then Certs = Certs.Find(CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_FIND_SUBJECT_NAME, name)
    Return Certs
End Function

Public Function SignBase64(ByVal Content As String, ByVal Name As String) As String
    Dim Certs As CAPICOM.Certificates
    Dim Cert As CAPICOM.Certificate
    Certs = findCertByName(Name)
    Cert = Certs.Item(1)
    Dim SignedData = New CAPICOM.SignedData
    Dim Signer = New CAPICOM.Signer With {
        .Options = CAPICOM_CERTIFICATE_INCLUDE_CHAIN_EXCEPT_ROOT,
        .Certificate = Cert
    }
    mOutType = CAPICOM_ENCODE_BINARY
    mOutType = CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64
    SignedData.Content = Content
    SignedBase64 = SignedData.Sign(Signer, False, mOutType)
    Return SignedBase64
End Function

Public Function UnSignBase64(ByVal Content As String) As String
    Dim Certs As CAPICOM.Certificates
    Dim Cert As CAPICOM.Certificate
    Dim SignedData = New CAPICOM.SignedData
    SignedData.Verify(Content, False, CAPICOM_VERIFY_SIGNATURE_ONLY)
    SignedBase64 = SignedData.Content
    Return SignedBase64
End Function

Public Function EncryptBase64(ByVal Content As String, ByVal Name As String) As String
    mOutType = CAPICOM_ENCODE_BINARY
    mOutType = CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64
    Dim Certs As CAPICOM.Certificates
    Dim Cert As CAPICOM.Certificate
    Certs = findCertByName(Name)
    Cert = Certs.Item(1)
    Dim EnvelopedData As CAPICOM.EnvelopedData = New CAPICOM.EnvelopedData
    EnvelopedData.Recipients.Add(Cert)
    EnvelopedData.Content = Content
    Dim EncBase64 As String = EnvelopedData.Encrypt(mOutType)
    Return EncBase64
End Function

Public Function DecryptBase64(ByVal Content As String) As String
    mOutType = CAPICOM_ENCODE_BINARY
    mOutType = CAPICOM_ENCODE_BASE64
    Dim EnvelopedData As CAPICOM.EnvelopedData = New CAPICOM.EnvelopedData
    EnvelopedData.Decrypt(Content)
    Dim EncBase64 As String = EnvelopedData.Content
    Return EncBase64
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Заранее скажу regsvr32 CAPICOM.dll не подходит, библиотека 32bit а у меня  Windows10 64bit. Собираю только только под 32bit, иначе не заработает библиотека.
В System32 тоже не помогает добавлять.

Comment: Можно попробовать сделать как тут DllImport https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229793/how-to-use-dllimport-in-vb-net  но тогда с библиотекой будет неудобно работать, при этом она работает в отладке и без этого... странно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело не в VB.NET, а в COM (Component Object Model), через который вы эту самую библиотеку и подключаете.

Когда вы создаете COM-объект, вы указываете не библиотеку в которой он лежит, а его CLSID. По этому CLSID среда исполнения находит нужную библиотеку через реестр. Соответственно, если вы переместили библиотеку в другое место - вам надо изменить соответствующую запись в реестре, найдя ее в ветке HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\CLSID\{ваш CLSID}\InprocServer32 (или в ветке HKLM\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\CLSID\{ваш CLSID}\InprocServer32 если это 32х-битная библиотека на 64х-битной винде)

Ну или можно попробовать зарегистрировать библиотеку через regsvr32.

Существуют также способы обойтись без реестра при COM-взаимодействии, но CAPICOM.dll их не использует.

---

Но в вашем случае все это не требуется: библиотека доступна в виде Redistributable-пакета. Вам не нужно ее никуда копировать и нигде регистрировать, вам нужно лишь установить этот самый пакет. Да, каждый пользователь вашей программы тоже должен будет установить этот пакет - но для того Redistributable-пакеты и существуют.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, теперь понятно почему программа себя так ведет. Реестр :)

Comment: У меня студия пока я экспериментировал наделала разных ключей в CLSID, а в ключах типа CLSID\{17E3A1C3-EA8A-4970-AF29-7F54610B1D4C}\TypeLib\{BD26B198-EE42-4725-9B23-AFA912434229} папки с моей библиотекой. Буду чистить.

Comment: @AlexS вы уверены что это студия наделала?

Comment: Нет, но удавив их я временно все Сломал. Потом починил путем регистрации regsvr32.exe F:\capicom.dll через админа. Главное указывать полный путь до dll, а не относительный типа .\ или ./ и регистрация прошла нормально. Вот путь до регистрации если копировать его из строки \HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Classes\TypeLib\{BD26B198-EE42-4725-9B23-AFA912434229}\2.1\0\win32